# Using jQuery Chosen to limit options based on a previous selection

Tags: jquery, html-select, jquery-chosen

I have two select options as noted below.

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <select id="industrySelect" class="chosen-industry-select" data-placeholder="select industry" multiple>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">Business</option>
    <option value="2">Education</option>
    <option value="3">Healthcare</option>
  </select>

  <select id="verticalMarketSelect" class="chosen-verticalMarket-select" data-placeholder="select vertical market" multiple>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1" industryValue="1">Retail</option>
    <option value="2" industryValue="1">Construction</option>
    <option value="3" industryValue="1">Automotive</option>
    <option value="4" industryValue="2">University</option>
    <option value="5" industryValue="2">Elementary School</option>
    <option value="6" industryValue="2">High School</option>
    <option value="7" industryValue="3">Hospital</option>
    <option value="8" industryValue="3">Doctor Office</option>
    <option value="9" industryValue="3">Dentist</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

The `industryValue` is simply an attribute I created for filtering purposes as the information for the selections are being pulled from two different SQL tables. `industryValue` directly relates to the value as noted in the options for `verticalMarketSelect` (i.e. industryValue="1" would relate to a selection of *Business* with a value of 1.

What I'm trying to accomplish is to only show options in the `verticalMarketSelect` if the corresponding option is selected from the `industrySelect` above. If no options are selected, the options for `verticalMarketSelect` should not be visible.

**EDIT:** I forgot a *very* important piece of information: I am using the jQuery Chosen plugin with both selects being multiple selects.

**EDIT:** I found some jQuery from a similar implementation, but it doesn't seem to work for my needs.

```
jQuery('#industrySelect').chosen().change(function() {
  var selected = [];
  jQuery('#industrySelect').find("option").each(function() {
    if (this.selected) {
      selected[this.value] = this;
    }
  })
  .each(function() {
    this.disabled = selected[this.value] && selected[this.value] !== this;
  });
  jQuery('#verticalMarketSelect').trigger("chosen:updated");
});
```

Comment: Do you want to hide entire `select#verticalMarketSelect` or do you want to display empty select?

Comment: I want to display an empty select. Or even better yet, have the select disabled until a selection is made in #industrySelect.

Comment: @SeanCallahan I edited my answer and added a demo please have a look at it. please consider that css is not present in the demo

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani thanks! Please see my edit above. Sorry for not mentioning it earlier!

Comment: @SeanCallahan I don't think it would make any difference. did you check the demo?

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani I did. It doesn't seem to fit the jQuery Chosen model.

Comment: Anyone have any more ideas on this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working and wanted to be sure to post the answer for anyone else that may want to implement something similar in the future. Thank you to everyone for your help!

```js
jQuery('#industrySelect').chosen().change(function() {
  var industrySelected = jQuery(this).chosen().val();
  var $verticalMarket = jQuery('select#verticalMarketSelect');
  var $verticalMarketHolder = jQuery('select#verticalMarketHolder');
  if (industrySelected == null) {
    $verticalMarket.empty();
  } else {
    $verticalMarket.find('option.existing').removeClass('existing');
    jQuery.each(industrySelected, function(index, value) {
      $verticalMarket.find('[industry="' + value + '"]').addClass('existing');
    });
    $verticalMarket.find('option').not('.existing').remove();
    jQuery.each(industrySelected, function(index, value) {
      var option = $verticalMarketHolder.find('[industry="' + value + '"]').clone();
      var existingOptions = $verticalMarket.find('[industry="' + value + '"]');
      if (existingOptions.length == 0) {
        $verticalMarket.append(option);
      }
    });
  }
  jQuery('#verticalMarketSelect').trigger('chosen:updated');
});
jQuery(function() {
  jQuery('#industrySelect').trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <select id="industrySelect" class="chosen-industry-select" data-placeholder="select industry" multiple>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1">Business</option>
    <option value="2">Education</option>
    <option value="3">Healthcare</option>
  </select>

  <select id="verticalMarketSelect" class="chosen-verticalMarket-select" data-placeholder="select vertical market" multiple>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="1" industryValue="1">Retail</option>
    <option value="2" industryValue="1">Construction</option>
    <option value="3" industryValue="1">Automotive</option>
    <option value="4" industryValue="2">University</option>
    <option value="5" industryValue="2">Elementary School</option>
    <option value="6" industryValue="2">High School</option>
    <option value="7" industryValue="3">Hospital</option>
    <option value="8" industryValue="3">Doctor Office</option>
    <option value="9" industryValue="3">Dentist</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you could use `.hide()` for this, but it seems that hiding `<option>` elements doesn't work in each browser, so you first need to save the full list, then remove the elements that do not comply to your query, and set the `.html()` of the `<select>`:

```
var originalValues;
$('#industrySelect').change(function() {
   if (!originalValues) {
      originalValues = {};
      $('#verticalMarketSelect').children().each(function() {
         var industryValue = $(this).attr('industryValue');
            if(!(industryValue in originalValues)){
             originalValues[industryValue] = [];
         }
         originalValues[industryValue].push([$(this).val(), $(this).html()]);
      });
   }

   $('#verticalMarketSelect').empty();
   for(var x in originalValues[$('#industrySelect').val()]){
      var v = originalValues[$('#industrySelect').val()][x];
    $('#verticalMarketSelect').append('<option value="'+v[0]+'">' + v[1] + '</option>');
   }

});
```

Comment: I completely forgot to mention I am using the jQuery chosen plugin with multiple selects. Sorry, Thomas!

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div style="display:none;" id = "sublist">
    <option value="1" industryValue="1">Retail</option>
    <option value="2" industryValue="1">Construction</option>
    <option value="3" industryValue="1">Automotive</option>
    <option value="4" industryValue="2">University</option>
    <option value="5" industryValue="2">Elementary School</option>
    <option value="6" industryValue="2">High School</option>
    <option value="7" industryValue="3">Hospital</option>
    <option value="8" industryValue="3">Doctor Office</option>
    <option value="9" industryValue="3">Dentist</option>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
    $('#industrySelect').change(function(){
         $('#verticalMarketSelect').empty();
         $('#verticalMarketSelect').append($('#sublist').find('option[industryValue="' + $(this).val()+'"]'));

});
```

Here is the [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/weapgpoh/)